# deconstructing word solution

Tags: python, list, while-loop

I have a word problem I am trying to solve but am getting stuck on a key part.

Initialize n to be 100. Initialize numbers to be a list of numbers from 2 to n, but not including n.
  With results starting as the empty list, repeat the following as long as numbers contains any numbers.

- Add the first number in numbers to the end of results.
- Remove every number in numbers that is evenly divisible by (has no remainder when divided by) the number that you had just added to results.

How long is result?

When n is 100, the length of results is 25.

So far I have understood to set n = 100, and a range(2, 100), results = []
and that the result will be an append situation as in results.append(numbers[]),
but I am having a mental block figuring the key of Remove every number in numbers that is divisible by the number that was added to results.

I know this will be a floor or modulo solution taking from one list to another and working via a while loop.  I can also figure the length will be len(results). Any assistance or guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @sashkello I was probably a bit premature, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your new number is `newnumber`, then you can select only elements from a list which are not divisible by it:

```
results = [x for x in results if x%newnumber!=0]
results.append(newnumber)
```

Here `newnumber` is added afterwards because it is more reasonable to do it (otherwise, it itself would be removed by the filtering).

If you insist on doing it in that order, then it's a bit uglier:

```
results.append(newnumber)
results = [results[i] for i in range(0,len(results)-1) if results[i]%newnumber!=0]
```

Comment: I must be dumb as a rock but can you put this in the terms I used in original question?  n and results and numbers.  I also realize this is getting at prime number in a backwards fashion.  Thanks.

Comment: @EricBaltrush Sorry, but the original question was asking how to remove certain numbers from the list. This answers it, I don't think it is useful for your own educational purposes if I simply write the whole code for you. All left to do for you is to initialize lists and write loop where you can copypaste the two lines above (newnumber would be the last number in numbers list). If you have a specific point where you are stuck, ask it in a separate question.

Comment: Thanks very much for the re-write.  I will work on it and see what I can come up with.  This was a crazy way to get prime numbers, which I realized was the result.

Comment: @EricBaltrush Welcome. Yep, this is a prime numbers exersize and certainly far from any efficient way of doing it. However, the point is to learn to code it and it is a nice way to learn a bit of list comprehensions.